# How prove this integral inequality$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{x^x}{\rm d}x<2 $

Tags: integration, integral-inequality

Show that$$
\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{x^x}{\rm d}x<2
$$

Comment: Wolfram Alpha says that integral is roughly $1.99546$, so $2$ is a pretty challenging upper bound to prove.

Comment: This question has been asked 1 day ago, maybe you are the friend of this [OP](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/909637/inequality-of-numerical-integration-int-0-infty-x-x-dx)?

Comment: You may find an answer there: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/909637/inequality-of-numerical-integration-int-0-infty-x-x-dx/909672#909672